# Transform a numpy 3D ndarray to a symmetric form with respect to a specific index

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array

In the case of a matrix mat n x n, i can do the following

```
sym = 0.5 * (mat + mat.T)
```

the operation gives the desired result sym[i,j] = sym[j,i]

Suppose we have a 3D array ndarr[i,j,k], where i,j,k 0,1,...n,
then ndarr is n x n x n. The idea is to obtain the following "symmetric" form 
nsym[i,j,k] = nsym[j,i,k] using ndarr. I tried this:

```
import numpy as np

# Generate some random matrix, n = 5
ndarr = np.random.beta(0.1,1,(5,5,5))

# First attempt to symmetrize
sym1 = np.array([0.5*(ndarr[:,:,k]+ndarr[:,:,k].T) for k in range(5)])
```

The problem here is that sym1[i,j,k] != sym1[j,i,k] as it is required. In fact I obtain sym1[i,j,k] = sym1[i,k,j], symmetric under the exchange of the last two symbols!

```
# Second attempt
sym2 = 0.5*(ndarr+ndarr.T)
```

Same problem here and sym2 is symmetric with respect the second index sym2[i,j,k]=sym2[k,j,i].

To resume, the goal is to find a symmetric form for a 3D array with respect to the third index and to preserve the values in the diagonal for the original ndarr[i,i,i].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not using the correct transpose:

```
sym = 0.5 * (ndarr + np.transpose(ndarr, (1, 0, 2)))
```

By default, `np.transpose` and the `.T` property will reverse the order of the axes. In your case, we want to only flip the first two axes: `(0,1,2) -> (1,0,2)`.

**EDIT**: The reason your first attempt failed is because you were concatenating each symmetrized matrix along the first axis, not the last. It's more clear if you make `ndarr` with shape `(5, 5, 3)`:

```
In [16]: sym = np.array([0.5*(ndarr[:,:,k]+ndarr[:,:,k].T) for k in range(3)])

In [17]: sym.shape
Out[17]: (3L, 5L, 5L)
```

In any case, the version above with `np.transpose` is cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: it works! I see, `.T` reverse the axes in order to extend the transpose to arrays with different axis dimensions (which is the expected behavior).But when i do the slices to work with nxn matrices (first attempt) i do not expect to have the axes reversed...

Comment: Sound clear! and I agree with the proposed solution.